# Related dropdown lists with Play Framework 2

Tags: java, scala, select, frameworks

I'm working with play framework 2 and I need two related dropdown lists. For example, in the first list will appear the letters of the alphabet and select a of them, in the second list containing words starting with that letter only.

Thanks.

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.index) {

         @select(
                formABC("letter"),

                options(DropDownList.letters),
                '_default -> "--- Choose a letter ---",
                '_label -> "Letter"
        )
            ...
            And here I need the other @select
```

Comment: You can put the code you have so far, that will help you get an answer.

Comment: I've updated with the code